# Proof verification: $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} x^{2} - 6x = -5$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I want to prove that the limit exists using the delta-epsilon limit definition. Please somebody verify my solution. The given problem is:

Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow1} x^2 -6x = -5$.

My solution:

> Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $0<\delta <1$ and $0<\delta<\epsilon/3$.
>
> If $0<|x-1|<\delta$, then $|x^2-6x+5| = |(x-5)(x-1)| = |x-5| |x-1|< |x-5|\delta < 3\delta < \epsilon$

Scratch work: Assume that $\delta \leq 1$, then $|x-1|<\delta<1$ implies that $-1<x-1<1$ and  $0<x<2$ so that $5<|x-5|<3$

Comment: Are you aware that you wrote that $5<3$ ?

Comment: Are you sure $5<|x-5|<3$?

Comment: @stity Unfortunately he didn't ;)

Comment: With the restriction $\delta\le 1$, all we can say is that $|x-5|\le 5$. So some change is needed.

Comment: 0<x<2 so that 5<|x−5|<3. I took away 5 on both sides.

Comment: @kunjimamu I think it would easier for you to memorize the code for the math symbols rather than having to copy and paste the symbols.  To get $\delta$, write \delta between dollar signs.  To get $\epsilon$, write \epsilon.  To get $\geq$, write \geq.  To get $\leq$, write \leq.

Comment: @kunjimamu Do you prefer if I give you 5 or 3 dollars?

Comment: @kunjimamu: Subtracting 5 from both sides gives you $-5 < x-5 < -3$. Therefore, $3 < |x-5| < 5$.

Comment: So do I choose 0<δ<ϵ/5?

Comment: @kunjimamu: Yep :-) The only improvement I suggest is to include the justification within the main argument instead of as "scratch work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to take $0<\delta<\min(1,\epsilon/5)$ and you are good to go